# Exception during date parsing

Tags: java

I have a pojo where during deserilization i was getting the following exception.

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "Jul 17, 2023 12:01:45 PM": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jul 17, 2023 12:01:45 PM': Cannot parse date "Jul 17, 2023 12:01:45 PM": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

pojo

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class B implements Serializable {

@JsonProperty("alarmtime")
Date alarmtime = new Date();
}
```

```
ObjectMapper  mapper = new ObjectMapper();
B def = mapper.readValue(doc.toString(), B.class);
```

doc is the document string present in the database or from other 3rd party api.

can anyone please help me.

Comment: Stop using the outdated class `java.util.Date` move over ti the newer `java.time` API

Comment: @cokachi I was going to help, but if you're like that... pass

Comment: @Jens You can change `Date` package or not depending on the size of your project, the agreement of your colleagues, etc. If the question is about `java.util.Date` it's about this class, and we have to do with it.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan I do not understand what you want to say. The suggestion to not use old outdated classes is always valid in my opinion. Especially if this class is outdated since decades

Comment: @Jens it is out of subject.

Comment: Re, "*give me the code"* -- a somewhat insulting request. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format of the date does not match the default format for jackson. Use [JsonFormat.pattern()](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html#pattern--) on the property to specify the correct format.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
```

Also, if possible don't use the outdated and error prone `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc. They were supplanted in java **8** by [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the modern java date-time API.